# C# Accessing Form1 Elements from a function in Form1

Tags: c#, winforms, object, static

I'm trying to create a C# application for a project. Since I have no experience in C#, I have had a hard time understanding how to reference Form elements. I need to change richTextBox1 content from a function and reference it from a DataReceivedHandler. Here is the code:

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    Form1 myform = new Form1();
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Debug.Print("Data Received:");
    Debug.Print(indata);
    addRichBox(indata); //????Problematic Line????
}

public void addRichBox(String text)
{
    String x;
    x = richTextBox1.Text;
    richTextBox1.Text = text + Environment.NewLine + x;

    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

What I want to do is simply call addRichBox function in the DataReceivedHandler, but it gives the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". I have tried making addRichBox static, and using something like this.addRichBox but those do not seem to work. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
It works now. I've done a little digging and found out how to invoke. Here it is:

```
public void addRichBox(String text)
{

    richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(text)));
    richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length));
    richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()));

}
```

Comment: You have two problems.  You must remove *static* from the DataReceivedHandler() method so you can directly call an instance method like addRichBox.  And it runs on a worker thread, that requires using the form's BeginInvoke() method to keep it thread-safe.  You'll encounter the 3rd problem when you discover the fire-hose problem, receiving data faster than you can display it, you'll notice from the UI freezing.

Comment: When static keyword is removed, System.InvalidOperationException is thrown.

Comment: Yes, that's why I explicitly mentioned you have two problems.  You must use BeginInvoke().